# How to make the scrapy web crawling framework keep following links?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to make a crawler that takes information off the SCP wiki and follow links for the next SCP and continue like so.

Using my current code, after data from the first followed link is extracted, the crawler stops following to the next link.

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "scp"
    start_urls = [
        'https://scp-wiki.wikidot.com/scp-002',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for scp in response.xpath('//*[@id="main-content"]'):
            yield {
                'title': scp.xpath('//*[@id="page-content"]/p[1]').get(),
                'tags': scp.xpath('//*[@id="main-content"]/div[4]').get(),
                'class': scp.xpath('//*[@id="page-content"]/p[2]').get(),
                'scp': scp.xpath('//*[@id="page-content"]/p[3]').get(),
                'desc': scp.xpath('//*[@id="page-content"]/p[6]').get(),
            }
        next_page = response.xpath('//*[@id="page-content"]/div[3]/div/p/a[2]/@href').get()
        next_page = 'https://scp-wiki.wikidot.com'+next_page
        print(next_page)
        next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
        print(next_page)
        yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

When I run this spider I get the following error:

```
next_page = 'https://scp-wiki.wikidot.com'+next_page
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

Comment: Apparently `response.xpath('//*[@id="page-content"]/div[3]/div/p/a[2]/@href').get()` returns `None`. Did you try to understand why?

Answer (score 1):

As the error clearly says, it cannot concatenate "NoneType" to str.

It means the `next_page` variable is not fetching any value from the mentioned xpath in the function `response.xpath().get()` in the previous line.

There is no matching xpath, so the `get()` returns `None`.

You can check the [documentation of Scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html).

Comment: how can i get it to retrieve the link?

Comment: As I can see, the page you are accessing, the next page button has the xpath `//*[@id="page-content"]/div[3]/div/p/a[2]` . The xpath you have mentioned is ending with `/@href` , by mistake probably. If it doesn't work, use any other selector or use the full xpath. Hope this helps. :)